# Proper way to handle angular UI message alerts

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

A friend I are debating best practice for handling messages pushed to the UI

Below is how I handled it:

```
<div class='{{AlertClass}}' ng-show="AlertMessage != null">{{AlertMessage}}</div>
```

And:

```
record.update($scope.account)
    .$promise
    .then(function (r) {
        $scope.AlertMessage = "Success! Record has been saved."
        $scope.AlertClass = "alert alert-success"
    }, function (r) {
        $scope.AlertMessage = "Error! Something didn't work."
        $scope.AlertClass = "alert alert-error"
    });
```

Using the method above, I can easily change the look and message to the end user

However my friend insists the correct way to do this is along the line of

```
<div class='alert' ng-class='{ 'alert-error' : errorExists, 'alert-success' : success }">{{alertMessage}}</div>
```

Is there an advantage to either? It feels like my method is easier to manage and easier to read. However his method utilizes ng-class

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure its matter of opinion. But I would have to agree with you or at least Not your friends approach. Why? Because it really clutters the html markup. If a bunch of html tags were populated so heavy like that it really makes the readability of the html worse. The worse the readability the harder the code will be to maintain.

After looking at this again. The best approach may be to use controlled templating. Using ng-if you could template out an error or success message. This may offer better readability well keeping it simple no clutter.